# Save the images from a Google Doc to Google Drive - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, drive

I am trying to download the images from a Google Doc to my personal Google Drive.
I had it up and running for a minute, but once I dropped the working code into a loop to capture *all* the images in my document, I encountered a bug. The code stopped saving images to my drive and started saving empty files that are 4k in size and decidedly not the .pngs I'm looking for. I'm relatively positive that I have not hit my daily quota, can any of you make sense of this?

Looking forward to your replies.

Here is my non-functioning function:

```
function imageExtract() {
  var documentName = "googleDoc";
  var wd = DocumentApp.openById("<GOOGLE DOC ID>");

  var imgCount = wd.getBody().getImages().length;                      // get the number of images
  
  for (var i = 0; i < imgCount; i++){
    var images = wd.getBody().getImages()[i].getAs('image/png');       // get the image blob at index 'i'
    var save = DriveApp.createFile((documentName + '-' + i), images);  // name + save the image to drive
    var imgUrl = save.getUrl();

    Logger.log('Saved Image ' + (documentName + '-' + i) + ": " + imgUrl); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `DriveApp.createFile((documentName + '-' + i), images)` is not correct. In your situation, `images` is a blob. So in this case, `createFile(blob)` is required to be used. In the case of `createFile(name, content)`, `content` is required to be the string type. I thought that this is the reason fo your issue.
- `wd.getBody().getImages()` has already been used at outside of for loop. So I think that this can be used in the loop.
- When the blob is retrieved from `wd.getBody().getImages()`, the mimeType is `image/png` as the default.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function imageExtract() {
  var documentName = "googleDoc";
  var wd = DocumentApp.openById("<GOOGLE DOC ID>");
  var images = wd.getBody().getImages();
  var imgCount = images.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < imgCount; i++){
    var image = images[i].getBlob().setName(documentName + '-' + i);
    var save = DriveApp.createFile(image);
    var imgUrl = save.getUrl();
    Logger.log('Saved Image ' + (documentName + '-' + i) + ": " + imgUrl);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)
- [createFile(name, content)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content)
- [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setnamename)

Comment: This worked brilliantly!
Thank you, Tanaike. 
I now see the err of my ways.

Comment: It only gets 5 images from my document which has about 16 images in it.

Comment: @TechNerdXp About your issue of `It only gets 5 images from my document which has about 16 images in it.`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So, can you post it as a new question by including the method for correctly replicating your issue? By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike I think it because the 5 images are inline images while all other are positionedImages

Comment: @TechNerdXp Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that your document has positioned images from your question. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this page that was trying do download an image from Google Docs or Slides, this is what I found works:

1. Right click and select "Save to Keep"

[image]

2. Go to Keep and you can now do "Save image as..."

[image]